# PHP remove item from array

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel-5

I know how to remove something from an array but in this case its a bit different. My code seems to generate this annoying item in the array called "*items", I'm not sure how to remove it.

I need it removing because my application visually displays all the data in the array and right now there's just a blank space because of this item.

**My code**

Basically in my code I have converted an object to an array like this

```
$accounts = Account::where('archive', false)->select('id', 'display_name')->get();

$accounts = (array) $accounts;
```

I'm 100% sure its to do with this. is there a way to remove the "*items" item from the array?

**I've tried**

```
array_pop($array);
```

this didn't work for me it just removed the last item before "*item"

```
unset($array['*item']);
```

This also didn't work, it just didn't unset anything at all.

**Picture**

[image: note the *items element being passed]

**EDIT**

I'm working on someone else's code here and there is **a lot** of random features and functions, writing and explaining the whole script would take a silly amount of time so I ***tried*** to include what I thought would be necessary.

Comment: I would suggest fixing the problem not masking the symptom

Comment: The picture is from your javascript console? How do you convert the PHP array to json?

Comment: that kind of looks like json formatted data with the value of `*items` being an array. If you unset/ remove then those values will disappear too

Comment: Where is the code that generates the output in the image?

Answer (score 0):

Casting your object with `(array)` may have a weird behavior here. You could try `toArray`:

```
$accounts = Account::where('archive', false)
    ->select('id', 'display_name')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

Then you could check the result with `dd`:

```
dd($accounts);
```

Comment: aah i see.. this would be the right answer then the only problem is the way im using the accounts it needs to be an object before. i didnt write the code for this im just trying to alter it but yes this would have been easier to work with an array rather than making it an object im still confused as to why the previous developer went through so much hassle

Answer (score 0):

Awkwardly i found an answer to this immediately after posting it..

Instead of using the following feats of code...

```
$accounts = Account::where('archive', false)->select('id', 'display_name')->get();
$accounts = (array) $accounts;
```

I used

```
foreach($account in $accounts){
    $test = new \stdClass();
    $test = (array) $test;
    $test[$index]['Revenue']      = (double) $account->revenue;
    $test[$index]['Expense']      = (double) $account->expense;
    $test[$index]['Profit']       = $account->sum;
    $test[$index]['ID']           = $id;
    $test[$index]['Account Name'] = $display_name;
}
```

this still is confusing however because ive tried making a new array and then adding the values through that but it wouldnt work..?

**EDIT**
 i fully understand this is a highly ineffecient way of doing things but im working with a deadline and this is working, if you have anything to add please do! ill review the criticism when i have time and hopefully i can improve the code with your help!